# Criando um novo Objeto, e populando suas propriedades, usando Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflexão, genéricos

Olá,

Preciso invocar um método via reflexão,

```
Method.invoke(Objeto, arg);
```

- Objeto -> objeto criado a partir de Class.newInstance()
- arg -> é o valor que quero passar. E eu sei que é uma String.

Mas o Parâmetro do método eu não sei, e se o parametro for algo diferente de uma String da erro.

Então para saber o tipo do parâmetro, busco ele através de reflexão

```
type = Method.getParameterTypes()[0]
```

A questão é, como transformar a variável String arg, em um Objeto do tipo type?

```
public static Object bindClass(Class c, Map<String, String> param) {
   //Novo objeto do tipo Class 
   Object newInstance = c.newInstance(); 

   for(String key : param.keySet()) {
       String value = param.get(Key);
       String nomeMetodo = "set" + key;
       Method method = null;

       for(Method m : newInstance.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()){
            if(m.getName().equals(nomeMetodo)){
                    method = m;
                    break;
            }
        }

        Class type = method.getParameterTypes()[0];


       //Fazer um CAST de value(String) para type 


       //Aqui é necessário passar um 'value' do mesmo tipo do método invocado, e nem sempre é o tipo String 
       method.invoke(newInstance, value);

    }
}
```

Comment: Por que precisa? Quase todo mundo que acha que precisa na verdade não precisa e tem solução melhor. Se você está chamando um método que você não sabe, que não tem uma assinatura conhecida é bem complicado ter utilidade. E parece que vai criar um complicador enorme e nem está indo no caminho certo.

Comment: O título diz uma coisa, mas o texto corrido diz outra.

Comment: Mineiro, realmente existe algo melhor, mas em uma versão mais recente de uma biblioteca que uso, porém não posso atualizar. O que estou tentando fazer é uma espécie de bind, onde passo um Cláss, do objeto, por exemplo pessoa, e um map<String,String> dos atributos e valores para preencher o objeto via método set, e então retornar esse objeto completo para a aplicação. Se houver ema forma melhor estou aberto a sugestões. Obrigado.

Comment: Olá, Marcelo. Consegue postar o que tentou até o momento e qual erro dá? Não ficou muito claro o que quer fazer. Como o Jefferson diz, o título também não bate com o texto da pergunta.